# Angular: lookup all providers implementing a specific interface

Tags: angular, strategy-pattern, service-locator

In my Angular (4+) application, I want to create a basic plugin mechanism:

- The extension point is defined as an interface
- Extensions implement that interface
- To find all extensions, I need to discover the implementations of that interface at runtime.

Example: interface `SearchStrategy` with implementations `PersonSearchStrategy` and `DocumentSearchStrategy` (both services, registered as providers).

**Is there a way to dynamically get instances of these services by querying for implementations of the `SearchStrategy` interface?** How?

(might be some [Injector](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) related functionality?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's kinda possible, provided if you register the services with `InjectionToken` and use provide `multi`.

You can create an injection token with interface.

```
export const SearchStrategyToken = new InjectionToken<SearchStrategy[]>('SearchStrategy');
```

In your module register:

```
providers: [
  {provide: SearchStrategyToken, useClass: PersonSearchStrategy, multi: true}, 
  {provide: SearchStrategyToken, useClass: DocumentSearchStrategy, multi: true},
]
```

In your component or service:

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {

  const services = this.injector
  .get(SearchStrategyToken); // return 2 items [ PersonSearchStrategy, DocumentSearchStrategy ]

  const personSearch = services.find(x => x.constructor.name === 'PersonSearchStrategy');

  const docSearch = services.find(x => x.constructor.name === 'DocumentSearchStrategy');

}
```

Code example provided here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clxr6k.

However, it would be good if you provide more details on your use case. Probably there are better solution than going for the above route.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm! For a working example see http://frostnova.ch/angular2 (code: https://github.com/pwalser75/angular2-demo/blob/master/src/app/services/search.service.ts)

Comment: This is basically how I'd do it.

My only quibble is how you inject it. I'd inject the token rather than the injector.

`constructor(@Inject(SearchStrategyToken) searchStrategies: SearchStrategy[]) {...}`